# Celery real time monitoring and Django app

Tags: django, celery, monitoring

Celery [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=my_monitor#real-time-processing) explain how to setup custom handling of events. This approach doesn't quite seem to work with my Django project and celery however.

My `celery.py` file looks like

```
from __future__ import absolute_import 
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

# The custom monitor copied from celery docs
def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        # task name is sent only with -received event, and state
        # will keep track of this for us.
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print('MY MON TASK FAILED: %s[%s] %s' % (
            task.name, task.uuid, task.info(), ))

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection,
                                   handlers={'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks, }
                                   )
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)


app = Celery('myproj')


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
# Monitoring
my_monitor(app)
```

I have just copied the example monitor from the docs.

I don't get an error, but launching either a celery worker/beat or django's runserver just seems to hang forver until I comment out the `my_monitor(app)` line.

What's the correct way to do this in a Django proj?

Answer (score 2):

**Monitoring and Managing Celery Tasks with Flower**

For real-time monitoring and management of Celery tasks, Flower is an excellent tool. It's a web-based application built on Tornado, providing a WebSocket server for streaming task events and statuses.

**Installation and Configuration:**

1. **Install Flower**: Use `pipenv` for dependency management, combining `pip` and `virtualenv`. Install Flower with:

   ```
   pipenv install flower
   ```
2. **Start Flower**: To monitor your Celery app, start Flower with:

   ```
   flower -A $projectname -l info
   ```

   Replace `$projectname` with your project's name.
3. **Start Celery Worker with Event Reporting**: Enable task monitoring in Flower by starting a Celery worker with:

   ```
   celery -A $projectname worker -E -B -l info
   ```

   Flags used:

   - `-E`: Enables events for task monitoring.
   - `-B`: Starts Celery Beat for scheduled tasks.

**Integrating with Django:**

To display task events within a Django app, you can create a template that listens to Flower's WebSocket and updates in real-time.

**Template Placement:**

- Place the template in your Django app's templates directory. For instance, if your app is named `myapp`, the path would be `myapp/templates/myapp/task_monitor.html`.
- Ensure your Django settings are configured to discover templates in your app's directories.

**Example Django Template:**

```html
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}  <!-- Note: base.html is updated to base_site.html for newer Django versions -->
{% load static %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
<title>Monitor Celery Task Events</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var ws_success = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555/api/task/events/task-succeeded/');
    ws_success.onmessage = function (event) {
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerText = event.data;
        outputDiv.appendChild(listItem);
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Events:</h2>
<ul><div id="output"></div></ul>
{% endblock %}
```

This template subscribes to the WebSocket endpoint `ws://localhost:5555/api/task/events/task-succeeded/`, displaying each task's success event as it comes in.

**WebSocket Endpoints:**

- For task success events: `ws://localhost:5555/api/task/events/task-succeeded/`
- For a dashboard overview: `ws://localhost:5555/dashboard`

**Further Steps:**

Ensure Celery is correctly configured within your Django project. This involves adjusting files like `$projectname/celery.py`, `$projectname/__init__.py`, and `celeryconfig.py`, following Celery's documentation.

**Additional Resources:**

- [Celery Documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/index.html) for Django integration.
- [Flower: Real-time Celery web monitor](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor).

With this setup, your Django application will have an interface for monitoring Celery tasks, leveraging Flower's comprehensive event tracking capabilities.

Comment: Adjusted the explanation accordingly

Comment: I cannot judge whether or not the solution works (as I've not used flower in this way) but this at least has the looks of an excellent answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

recv.capture is a blocking call. Did you get any output from your event handler?

If you're trying to use your django server as both a monitor and a task producer/consumer, that's not going to work.

Your monitor should be a separate stand-alone application. You should also consider eliminating the django dependency as it's unnecessary.